# How to get one property from Ilist<T> where other properties are True

Tags: c#, list, linq, ienumerable

I'm trying to select `ID` from an `Ilist<T>` where 2 boolean properties are equal true

```
myList.Select(t => t.IsValid && t.IsBalance).Distinct().ToList();
```

but if I want to return and select only the `t.ID` where  `t.IsValid` and  `t.IsBalance` how to do so ? I couldn't find an example

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Where` for the filtering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Select` for projection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
myList.Where(t => t.IsValid && t.IsBalance).Select(t => t.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can also use query syntax:

```
var result = (from t in myList
              where t.IsValue && t.IsBalance
              select t.ID).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Oh, any idea why projection and filtering in IList interface are so confusing and backwards of the typical SQL operations? hahah Usually we project first than we filter . Anyways I very appreciate your help , thanks !

Comment: @napi15 - in SQL `select` is used to determine which fields to retrieve and not any record filtering. Also, in SQL when your query executes it first performs the where clause if present and only later the select.

Comment: @napi15 SQL has it backwards, so I guess regular way may seem confusing after being used to the backwards SQL way :]

Comment: @Slai You're totally right , because when I studied Data Base optimizations I learned about the operation orders but I discovered everyone has it backward till today where I finally realized it's the SQL who has it backward all this time